# Issue with using AVR TWI interface

Tags: arduino, avr, i2c, atmel, atmega

I'm trying to access HMC5883L module using atmega2560. I've written a class (I2C) containing basic methods essential for I2C communication.

First, I'll explain the problem. This is what I've done.

```
int main(){
    I2C i2c;  //an object with basic I2C communication methods

    i2c.init();
    i2c.start();
    i2c.sendSLAW();
    ...
    i2c.write(...);
    ...  //configure registers, CRA, CRB, MR ...
    i2c.stop();
    while (1)
    {
        i2c.start();        
        i2c.sendSLAR();     
            .... //read x,y,z register values
        i2c.stop();     
            .... //say, display x,y,z readings
        _delay_ms(500);
    }
}
```

(Consider the terms have their ordinary meanings. SLAW = SLA+W (Slave address + write)...)

Everything goes well till it comes to the while loop. In the loop, it seems to be get stucked at `i2c.stop()`

`i2c.stop()` is implemented like this;

```
void I2C::I2C_stop(){
    TWCR = (1<<TWINT)|(1<<TWSTO)|(1<<TWEN);
    while (TWCR & (1<<TWSTO));
}
```

Have i done something wrong ? How can i solve this?

(All other functions are implemented simply as in the datasheet examples.)

Answer (score 0):

```
while (TWCR & (1<<TWSTO));
```

doesn't look right. The TWSTO flag indicates stop, and you correctly write to it to stop. But it stays 1, which produces an infinite loop. If anything, you will want

```
while !(TWCR & (1<<TWSTO));
```

but the code examples don't have a loop at all.